# What does "place an order with" mean?

Tags: meaning

Adeline speaks about Vincent's last letter:

> Adeline: The day before he killed himself. When he handed it to me, he said it was urgent.
> And, you know I asked if there was anything wrong. And, he said he'd run out
> of paints and he placed a big order for some more 'cause he had lots
> of paintings planned. Don't you think that's odd to **place an order with** his brother
> if money was an issue between them and then to kill himself the next day?

What does "place an order with" mean?

Comment: Please tell us what you understand so far. Have you looked up "place an order" in a dictionary? (The previous sentence uses it too: "placed a big order".) Is it the "with" that you couldn't interpret?

Comment: @TimPederick Does it mean his brother also paying money for that order?

Comment: Okay, so it does sound like “with” is the problem. It can mean either “A buys **from** B”, or “A and B buy **together** (from C)”. The first is more common (and very likely correct here), but the second is possible. Do we know if Vincent’s brother sells paint? That’s important context for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the previous sentence it says

> he placed a big order for some more [paints]

When you "place an order" it means you tell someone what you want to buy from them and agree a price (you might pay when you place the order or you might pay later). You say "with X" to mean the person that you are buying from

Vincent wanted to buy paints from his brother. He told his brother what paints he wanted to buy on the day before he died.

Adeline thinks it strange that Vincent would place a big order for paint if he was planning to kill himself. And it is strange that he would place a big order for paint with his brother if they were arguing about money.